# Marshal.AllocHGlobal is allocating more memory than expected

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management

I am using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` c# method to allocate memory for a IntPtr and then copying the contain of a byte[]:

```
byte[] clientIpAddr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("127.0.0.1")
IntPtr client_ipAddr_p = IntPtr.Zero;
ipAddress_p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(clientIpAddr.Length);
Marshal.Copy(clientIpAddr, 0, ipAddress_p, clientIpAddr.Length);
```

Then I pass the pointer to a C++ external library that receive my variable like this:

```
int open_socket(char *clientIpAddr_p)
{
    <open a socket>
}
```

According to the definition of `AllocHGlobal` it eventually could reserve more memory than expected (which I can assure because I am now suffering it). The problem is that I need my `IntPtr` to have exactly the size I am requesting because I need the IP to be exact to open a socket afterwards.

Is there a better way to allocate external memory that assure the `char *` to have my correct IP?

Comment: No, no... The C/C++ text the `char*` pointer clientIpAddr_p points to needs to be zero-terminated. so that the open_socket function can determine the length of the string correctly.  So you need to allocate a buffer that has a size of **atleast** string length + 1 (it is okay to allocate more), with the byte/char directly following the string characters being a `\0` byte/char. (A pointer in C/C++ does not carry any information about the length/size of the data it points to.) I guess spending some time with a C/C++ tutorial covering pointers and zero-terminated strings would be time well spend

Comment: Then this is the answer to my question, thanks!

Comment: I don't know how you invoke the C/C++ code from .NET. If it were possible for you to directly pass the string as argument when P/Invoking the native C/C++ function from .NET, then the .NET marshaller can automatically take care of converting the .NET string into a pointer pointing to a zero-terminated C string, saving you the hassle of manually allocating and filling the char/string buffer for the C/C++ function, and thus making your code both simpler and possibly more robust...

Comment: @elgonzo Why not post an answer rather than comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a problem that *Marshal.AllocHGlobal* allocates more then the specified amount of memory. Your code suffers from a different and quite likely fatal problem.

`open_socket(char *clientIpAddr_p)` expects a pointer to a C-style [null-terminated string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) (also known as NUL-terminated string, zero-terminated string or ASCIIZ). However, your C# code creates a buffer and fills it with the string characters/bytes without terminating it with a null character. Quite possibly this will make the *open_socket* function crash or otherwisely misbehave when searching the memory (starting at the address given by the pointer) for the missing null character.

A possible fix would be rather simple: Allocate the buffer with a size of `clientIpAddr.Length + 1`, accounting for the terminating null character. The zero-terminator (a null byte) has to be set explicitly, since *Marshal.AllocHGlobal* does *not* initialize/fill the allocated buffer with null bytes. Since we are dealing with an ASCII/ANSI string here the null character is simply a byte with a value of zero.

```
byte[] clientIpAddr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("127.0.0.1")
IntPtr client_ipAddr_p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(clientIpAddr.Length + 1);
Marshal.Copy(clientIpAddr, 0, ipAddress_p, clientIpAddr.Length);
Marshal.WriteByte(client_ipAddr_p, clientIpAddr.Length, 0);
```

Okay, forget about the code i just wrote. ;-)

Why? Because there is an even simpler "one-stop" solution to the problem, saving you from the hassle of manually allocating and filling the buffer for the C-style null-terminated string: The [**`Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi) method, which will convert your .NET string with the IP address directly into a corresponding C-style null-terminated ANSI string.

```
string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
IntPtr client_ipAddr_p = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(ipAddress);
```

---

(Unless the *open_socket* function requires the string buffer pointed at by *clientIpAddr_p* to continue existing after calling it, free the allocated buffer using the `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` method after calling the native function, irregardless of whether the buffer has been allocated using *Marshal.AllocHGlobal* or *Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi*.)